# Regex match website that is NOT an email

Tags: regex, web-scraping, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to extract websites without matching email addresses.

In other words if my contact section has

> email: a@gmail.com ---- website: www.company.com

I want the www.company.com **without** matching gmail.com.

So far I have tried everything that I can think of, the best I have so far is

```
\b(?:.(?<!@))+\.\S+\b
```

but that will still match gmail.com in a@gmail.com.

I'll admit that my Regex skills are not the strongest, I've done my research regarding negative lookaheads/behinds etc but I still don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expression made by JGSoft for domain names:

```
\b(?<!@)((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b
```

It is internationalized and strict.

I added `(?<!@)` to stop it from matching domain names after email names.

<kbd>[See a demo here](http://regex101.com/r/aW1gK0)</kbd>